# Return column names to a list if value in column is true

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that contains 16 columns. My goal is to return a 17th column containing all the column names in list or tuple format if the cell contained a certain value. The purpose is to efficiently store data from a multi-select survey question so that Python's .explode or SQL's UNNEST methods can be used to count the items in the 17th column.

A sample dataset:

```
| Q1    |  Q2   |  Q3   |
|-------|-------|-------|
| True  | True  | False |
| False | True  | True  |
| True  | True  | False |
```

What I'd like to return:

```
| Q1    |  Q2   |  Q3   |   List   |
|-------|-------|-------|----------|
| True  | True  | False | [Q1, Q2] |
| False | True  | True  | [Q2, Q3] |
| True  | True  | False | [Q1, Q2] |
```

I'm open to other solutions if I'm not quite thinking about this issue the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll go with a classic python way. I hope you can get your data into a dictionary called `data` like this...

```
data={'Q1':['True', 'False', 'True'], 'Q2':['True', 'True', 'True'], 'Q3':['False', 'True', 'False']}
output = []
for i in range(len(data)):
    z=[]
    for j in data:
        if data[j][i] == 'True':
            z.append(j)
    output.append(z)
print(output)
# [['Q1', 'Q2'], ['Q2', 'Q3'], ['Q1', 'Q2']]
```

Comment: I can convert the dataframe to a dictionary and I can use Pandas -- I'm happy to find the solution in pure Python or that library. If I do that, the dictionary looks like:

{ Q1: {0: False, 1: True, 2: False}
  Q2: {0: True, 1: False, 2: False}
}

(And so on...)

Comment: This actually outputs `[['Q1', 'Q2'], ['Q1', 'Q2'], ['Q1', 'Q2']]`.

Comment: @phihag yes the output is clearly mentioned in the code.

Answer (score 1):

While [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61661287/12406828) solution works for the specific question, I think it only works for NxN dict,list shapes e.g. add a 'Q4' key with a list length 3, or, drop a value from each list and it will break. I found this to be more robust personally even if not the most pythonic...

```
import itertools
data={'Q1':['True', 'False', 'True'], 'Q2':['True', 'True', 'True'], 'Q3':['False', 'True', 'False']}

output = []
for k,v in data.items():
    z=[]
    for i in v:
        if i =='True':
            z.append(k)
        else:
            z.append(None)
    output.append(z)
print(output)
#[['Q1', None, 'Q1'], ['Q2', 'Q2', 'Q2'], [None, 'Q3', None]]

output1 = list(map(list, itertools.zip_longest(*output, fillvalue=None)))

output2 = output1.copy()
print(output2)
#[['Q1', 'Q2', None], [None, 'Q2', 'Q3'], ['Q1', 'Q2', None]]

for x in output2:
    while None in x:
        x.remove(None)

print(output2)
#[['Q1', 'Q2'], ['Q2', 'Q3'], ['Q1', 'Q2']]
```

Answer (score 1):

A generic approach to such data compression problems is to define your own aggregation function. Here you could use a list comprehension:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Q1': [True, True, False],
                   'Q2': [True, False, True],
                   'Q3': [False, True, True]})

df['true_columns'] = df.agg(lambda s: [col for i, col in enumerate(df.columns) 
                                           if s[i]], axis=1)

print(df)
```

```
      Q1     Q2     Q3  true_columns
0   True   True  False      [Q1, Q2]
1   True  False   True      [Q1, Q3]
2  False   True   True      [Q2, Q3]
```

You may also want to consider using something like [scipy.sparse](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/sparse.html).

Comment: This code works well, and is much more succinct and clearer! Thanks! (I used this solution +- refactoring it into a function)

Comment: Caveat: the above solution is broken for NaN/missing values. (It returns them as if they were true/present)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `csv.DictReader` and do something like this:

```
import csv

my_data = csv.DictReader(input_file)
for row in all_rows:
    # ... do stuff based on row 
    new_col = []
    for col in my_data.fieldnames:
        # do stuff in the column
        if row[col] is True:
            new_col.append(col)
```

In the end if you need to append that column to the existing table you'll need to do a copy of the original `my_data` and append `new_col`

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[True,True,False],[True,False,True],[False,True,True]], 
columns = 
['q1','q2','q3'])

dict_map = {i:col for i,col in enumerate(df.columns)}

def check(x):    
   s = []
   for v,i in zip(x.values,x.index):
     if v: s.append(dict_map[i])
   return s

df['calc'] = df.apply(check).values
```

You get

```
      q1     q2       q3    calc
 0  True    True    False   [q1, q2]
 1  True    False   True    [q1, q3]
 2  False   True    True    [q2, q3]
```

Comment: This solution worked but terminated with ```KeyError: 17```. I should have mentioned that the rows have an index, and the second row has "17" as its index value.

Comment: That's weird, could you please check if the dict_map variable is correct according to your df?

Comment: `check` can be written shorter & clearer & faster as `def check(x): return [dict_map[i] for v,i in zip(x.values,x.index) if v]`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can create this 2 list from DataFrame by iterating the DF

```
quarters = ["Q1","Q2","Q3"]
data = [[True, True, False],[False, True, True], [True,True,False]]

qlist = []
slist = []
for item in data:
    slist = []
    for i,c in enumerate(item):
        if (c):
            slist.append(quarters[i])
    qlist.append(slist)
print(qlist)



 Output:
 ['Q1', 'Q2'], ['Q2', 'Q3'], ['Q1', 'Q2']]
```

You can iterate this result to update the last column. HTH

Comment: I like the data structure (except that it's very dangerous to use it with a 3x3 example, because you can mix up the indexing), but why not `qlist = [[quarters[i] for i, c in enumerate(item) if c] for item in data]`? That's much shorter, clearer, and faster.